# How to use rupee symbol in Dell keyboard?

Tags: windows-7, keyboard

I have Dell Latitude laptop and it has both Indian rupee symbol and euro in keyboard. But don't know how to use it. What keys can I press to insert the symbols?

I'm using Windows 7.

[image: Keyboard]

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/616274/typing-indian-rupee-symbol-with-windows-8-keyboard

Answer (score 11):

I went to the language page in control panel and changed it to Indian from US keyboard.

Voila: <kbd>Right Alt</kbd> + <kbd>4</kbd> gives Indian Rupee (₹). <kbd>Left Alt</kbd> + <kbd>4</kbd> gives dollar symbol ($).

Comment: you can also change keyboard input language from taskbar tray if you have multiple language installed.
http://images.dotnetschools.com/Common/changeKeyBoardInputLanguage.PNG

Comment: `Right Alt + 4` works perfectly for me and gives me ₹ symbol. But for $, don't you mean `Shift + 4`?

Comment: working for windows OS but not for ubuntu.

Answer (score 3):

We need to install windows driver update and some configurations. Kindly check this article. [Type Indian Rupee Symbol using Keyboard Keys](http://tipstricksandwe.blogspot.in/2011/12/type-indian-rupee-symbol-using-keyboard.html)

> - Download the Microsoft driver update which enable the Windows to detect rupee symbol. You can download Microsoft update which supports
>     rupee symbol from [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2496898).
> - Download the appropriate version of the update based on your version of Windows.  Once download completes, install the update.
> - In Control Panel, click Clock, Language, and Region, and then click Change keyboards or other input methods.
> - On the Region and Language screen, click Change keyboard on the Keyboards and Languages tab.
> - On the Text Services and Input Languages screen, click Add.
> - On the Add Input Language screen select English (India), and then select the India keyboard check box.
> - Restart the system.
> - Now your keyboard will be able to write rupee symbol.
> - For writing rupee symbol now on wards use Ctrl+Alt+₹(4 or $ on regular key). The Keyboards without rupee symbol, can use Ctrl+Alt+$

Comment: this is not needed for the XPS

Answer (score 2):

Hitting the **Right** side <kbd>Alt</kbd> and then the Rupee symbol will trigger the Rupee key entry. For Euro, it's the same - the **Right** side <kbd>Alt</kbd> -and hitting the Euro key will trigger the Euro symbol.

Stumped me for few minutes when I had a review copy of the XPS ultrabook.

Comment: Alt and rupee symbol is not working for me. Is it becuase the font is not supported the symbol?

Comment: Which OS, which application are you trying out? Did you hit the right side Alt key? The left side Alt key will **not** work

Comment: Win &, I tried in notepad and MS Office Word. I tried right side Alt key only. Any special font required?

Comment: Worked fine for me in Word. You are pressing Alt & the Rupee symbol simultaneously right? @Antoops

Comment: any specific font you tried?

Comment: @Antoops No, whatever was the default. Did the keys look like -- > http://i.stack.imgur.com/mzmlZ.jpg ?

Comment: Not sure if it'll have any impact, but in your localisation settings, are you using the correct keyboard layout? Without seeing the system, I'd bet you're using a keyboard layout where the Alt-Gr set isn't mapped...  as a temp workaround - it's U+20B9 if you want to locate it in Charmap or alt-8377 on the numeric keyboard (note: that's alt, NOT alt-gr).. ah, and I'm assuming you're talking about the new symbol, and not the old Rs symbol too..

Comment: Actually, you have to set English (India) either as only or default language. As said [here](http://superuser.com/a/616398/135529). Also, you can use `Ctrl + Shift + 4` for the same. #₹

Answer (score 1):

Mine is Dell XPS. <kbd>Left Alt</kbd> is working well. But for Rupee symbol, when I use <kbd>Left Alt</kbd>+<kbd>4</kbd>, it shows `¤` symbol. When I use <kbd>Left Alt</kbd>+<kbd>5</kbd>, it shows `€` (Euro symbol). Here Rupee symbol alone not displayed.

After a long search I got the solution. In Dell laptop, if the symbols are not displayed this means we have to update the drivers. Go to [Microsoft Support KB2496898](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2496898) to download the updates and then try using the same key combinations.

Comment: Santhosh answer will be perfectly useful for some people like me. Un necessarly DON'T give down-vote to others without thinking anything.

Answer (score 0):

For all Dell notebooks after the XPS Ultrabook:

Control Panel > Clock Language and Region Option

Change your input method to English(India) for rupee and English United Kingdom for Euro. Then you can use it by hitting the left <kbd>Alt</kbd> and the respective keys simultaneously.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print rupee symbol then it has certain codes that will allow you to print it, you can try now in chrome browser too. According to operating  system you are using here i listed the codes

- Ubuntu 10.10:  2 0 b 9, then
- MS Windows: Press-and-hold  2 0 b 9, then release
- Kubuntu 10.10: Copy-and-paste '₹'
- HTML: insert "₹"

Answer (score 0):

I went to the language settings (right click on the keyboard icon + settings) then added a French Keyboard.
After selecting that keyboard <kbd>Right Alt</kbd> + <kbd>5</kbd> worked right away.
The underlying idea is that US keyboards don't know Euros regardless of what is printed on the key.