# Typing Indian Rupee symbol with Windows 8 keyboard

Tags: windows-8, keyboard-layout, symbols, currency-format

I bought a Dell Inspiron 15R laptop. I don't know how to use the keyboard to type the new Indian Rupee symbol (₹). I searched Google and found an answer i.e. to hit the right <kbd>Alt</kbd> or <kbd>AltGr</kbd> key and then <kbd>4</kbd>, but this is not working for me. Someone suggested trying <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>4</kbd> but that too didn't work. How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 3):

Set **English (India)** as your default (or only) display language and keyboard layout/input method. See my answer [here](https://superuser.com/a/480566/138343), [this page](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/change-keyboard-layout) or [this guide](http://www.askvg.com/fix-cant-type-and-other-symbols-in-windows-8-incorrect-character-appears-on-screen/) for details:

[image: 1]

Once you've done so the Indian Rupee symbol (₹) should be available on pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>4</kbd> or <kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>4</kbd>:

[image: 2]

Comment: you can also change keyboard input language from taskbar tray if you have multiple language installed. http://images.dotnetschools.com/Common/changeKeyBoardInputLanguage.PNG

Answer (score 0):

Typing the Ascii codes (American Standard Code for Information Interchange) needs NumPad and ALT key. so without Numpad you can not do this. But there is a way to use Numbers Above the Letter keys as NumPad keys;
On LAPTOPS there is no NomPad usually. So you have to hit FN key then use the Numbers above the letter keys as NumPad numbers.

Now, you just need to hit ALT key down and use NumPad keys.

**Summary:**
Hit `Alt` + ( `FN` + `4` )

Answer (score 0):

The rupee symbol is pretty new, and only used in india, so its likely that your keyboard layout does not support it as is. Modern versions of windows do, and allow you to use the alt code <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>8</kbd><kbd>3</kbd><kbd>7</kbd><kbd>7</kbd> to type it in. Alternately you might be able to customise your keyboard to support the sign, if you use it often - assuming setting it to an indian localisation dosen't help. Microsoft's own layout editor dosen't seem to support windows 8, so you'd probably want to try AHK or sharpkeys

Comment: ╣ <- that's what I get for Alt+8377 switched to En_IN, still the same.

Answer (score 0):

Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + (key on which the symbol is provided)

On my Dell Vostro, it is on the key 4. And see, it works. ₹