# How to use the Indian Rupee symbol in Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, keyboard-layout

I have a Dell KB212-B USB keyboard, and it has both the Indian Rupee symbol and the Euro symbol in the keyboard. But I don't know how to use it. What keys should I press to insert the symbols?
I am using Windows XP.

Comment: Check this page out: `http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/20b9/index.htm`. I'm on linux so can't really try. It's the ALT+[numbers] code that you use to type this kind of characters. Try using this `ALT + 8377` type numbers in sequence while holding Alt

Comment: You can also try searching for a correct keyboard layout (Indian layout or something)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use rupee symbol in Dell keyboard?](http://superuser.com/questions/417528/how-to-use-rupee-symbol-in-dell-keyboard)

Answer (score 2):

Normally in all dell keyboards the right side <kbd>alt</kbd> button will allow you to trigger the <kbd>rupee symbol</kbd> and for euro the same <kbd>right alt</kbd>+<kbd>euro</kbd> key will work.

i tried this from sathya's answer over [here](https://superuser.com/questions/417528/how-to-use-rupee-symbol-in-dell-keyboard),it works fine on kb212-B keyboard

Answer (score 0):

There is another way. Hold the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key and type:

- <kbd>0</kbd><kbd>1</kbd><kbd>2</kbd><kbd>8</kbd> for the Euro symbol or
- <kbd>8</kbd><kbd>3</kbd><kbd>7</kbd><kbd>7</kbd> for the Indian Rupee symbol

On the Internet there are multiple Windows Alt keycode tables. One is for example here: http://www.marathon-studios.com/unicode/categories/Sc/Currency_Symbol

Comment: Note that this answers a different question, not the one that was actually asked, which was how to use the keys on that keyboard _that have the Euro and Rupee symbols printed on them_ to type the Euro and Rupee symbols.